# Xero Authentication: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, xero-api

I am trying to build a little script that will search Xero's transactions using a CSV that contains the transactions reference number.

When I run my code, I am getting unauthorized response. Below is my code:

```
import requests
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from flask import Flask, request

# Set up OAuth 2.0 credentials
client_id = 'REDACTED'
client_secret = 'REDACTED'
redirect_uri = 'REDACTED'
authorization_url = 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize'
token_url = 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token'
api_base_url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0'

# Generate the authorization URL
def generate_authorization_url():
    params = {
        'response_type': 'code',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'scope': 'openid profile email accounting.transactions offline_access',

    }
    query_string = urlencode(params)
    return f'{authorization_url}?{query_string}'

# Retrieve authorization code from callback URL
def retrieve_authorization_code(callback_url):
    authorization_code = None
    if 'code' in callback_url:
        authorization_code = callback_url.split('code=')[1].split('&')[0]
    return authorization_code

# Exchange authorization code for access token
def exchange_authorization_code(authorization_code):
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': authorization_code,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('access_token')
    else:
        raise Exception('Error exchanging authorization code for access token.')

# Search for transactions using the CSV file and the "Details" column
def search_transactions(access_token, csv_file, column_name):
    transactions = []
    not_found_transactions = []

    # Load transactions from CSV file
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        csv_data = list(csv_reader)

    # Search for transactions in Xero
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    for row in csv_data:
        details = row[column_name]
        # Search transactions by details
        params = {
            'where': f'Details=="{details}"'
        }
        response = requests.get(f'{api_base_url}/BankTransactions', headers=headers, params=params)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            search_result = response.json().get('BankTransactions')
            if search_result:
                transactions.extend(search_result)
            else:
                not_found_transactions.append(row)
        else:
            print(f'Error searching transactions in Xero. Status Code: {response.status_code}')
            print(f'Response Content: {response.content}')
            raise Exception('Error searching transactions in Xero.')

    return transactions, not_found_transactions

# Start a simple Flask web service on http://localhost:3000
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Web service is running.'

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    callback_url = request.url
    authorization_code = retrieve_authorization_code(callback_url)
    if authorization_code:
        # Exchange authorization code for access token
        access_token = exchange_authorization_code(authorization_code)

        # Search for transactions using the CSV file and the "Details" column
        csv_file = 'transactions.csv'
        column_name = 'Details'
        transactions, not_found_transactions = search_transactions(access_token, csv_file, column_name)

        # Print matched transactions
        print('Matched Transactions:')
        for transaction in transactions:
            print(transaction)

        # Print not found transactions
        print('Not Found Transactions:')
        for transaction in not_found_transactions:
            print(transaction)

    return 'Authorization code retrieved successfully.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Generate the authorization URL
    auth_url = generate_authorization_url()
    print(f'Please visit the following URL to authorize the app: {auth_url}')

    # Run the Flask web service on http://localhost:3000
    app.run('localhost', 3000)
```

I have read through all documentation that Xero provides and I believe I have implemented all steps to successfully get authenticated but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried printing the result of `exchange_authorization_code()` to make sure it's getting an appropriate token value?

Comment: Thanks for the response John. Correct, i have added a print to 'exchange_authorization_code()' to see if we are getting the correct token. Based on the results it is getting the correct token. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This might not be a problem, but why are you setting a header of `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, when you're sending a GET request that clearly **isn't** json?